# Is there a shortcut in Eclispe to find all appearances of a variable in a file?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is there a way in Eclipse to easily find all appearances of a variable in a file without having to manually search (CTRL + F) for it?

Comment: You can use CTRL+SHIFT+G to see the occurrences, but you may prefer to use ALT+K which jumps to the next occurrence of any highlighted variable quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the cursor on the variable, press ctrl-shift-g.  Works for variables, classes, methods, works across the entire project.  If you just click on the variable, eclipse will highlight all uses of the variable in the current file, and mark the scrollbar with the places that are highlighted.

Comment: CTRL + G is a bit of an overkill, but actually I didn't notice that Eclipse marks the scroll bar with the occurrences. Awesome, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a search with many features accessible with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, but it does not support variables inside of a function.

There is also another search, which occurs when you select a variable or other thing and press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to find all occurrences of variable to rename it, you can do it using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.